# AJAX load function, re-orgainze code to show specific sections of page

Tags: jquery

I have a page named `index.html`. On it, I have a **menu** with the 2 options below:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃   Classes   ┃ Update calendar ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

And then I have an empty `div` where I put the **contents** of the page:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

There's also an external JavaScript file (`menu.js`) which manages the menu options. <sup>(code below)</sup>

Then, on `calendar.php` I store two controls: a **calendar** and a **login form**. <sup>(code below)</sup>
The idea is:

- when the user clicks on the `Update calendar` option, `calendar.php` will be loaded into the contents `div` but only the **login form** will show.
- when the user clicks on the `Classes` option, `calendar.php` will be loaded into the contents `div` but only the **calendar** will show.

I'm currently using `$(selector).load(url)` to load `calendar.php` (see below).
The `Update calendar` option works as expected,
but when I click on `Classes`, **both** calendar *and* login form show up.

---

**menu.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var sections = $("#menu li");
        var loading = $("#loading");
        var content = $("#content");

        sections.click(function(){ //When the user clicks an option...
            showLoading(); //show the loading bar

            switch(this.id) {
                case "classes"://if the Classes option is clicked...
                    content.load("calendar.php", hideLoading); break;

                case "classes_update"://if the Update calendar option is clicked...
                    content.load("calendar.php #section_update", hideLoading); break;

                default: //if nothing is clicked...
                    hideLoading(); break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**calendar.php**

```
<head>
    <!-- links to JQuery resources -->

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!-- other calendar styles -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendar"></div> <!-- calendar area -->

    <div id="section_update"> <!-- login form area -->

        <!-- form stuff -->

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have **rewritten** your question to help people understand your problem. Please, **review** and correct any wrong thing.

Comment: jmendeth: Thank you very much! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this. Wow! This community has wonderful people willing to go that extra mile to reformat my question! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling and scouring the ajax/jquery information on the web, I spotted what seemed to give me some hopes. And voila!! it worked.

On the page **menu.js** in the switch statement code for "Classes" menu option, I used an ajax callback function and simply set the html property of the **login form** to be an empty div like this

$('#section_update').html('');

And that did the trick!

Thank you all, and my special thanks to "jmendeth" who helped me reformat my question so it can be better understood!.

Comment: One last thing. ;-) Look at your answer and notice: the HTML code isn't visible. To solve this, just put **4 spaces** before the line of code.